# How do i arrange images inside a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am making a project for Uni where I need to upload images to with specified width and height for everyone to see. Its basically equivalent of this: http://www.milliondollarhomepage.com/ . The problems is i have this for the HTML side:

```
<div id="canvas">
</div>
```

This is where the pictures are supposed to be uploaded, lets say its size is 1000 x 1000. I am supposed to fit every image there without change its dimensions.

```
const canvas=document.getElementById('canvas')
const btn = document.getElementById('submit-button');
const image_width=document.getElementById('image_width');
const image_height=document.getElementById('image_height');

btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    var x=document.createElement('img');
    var color=document.getElementById('color');
    if(color.value==='red')
    {
        x.src='red.png';
    }
    else if(color.value==='blue')
    {
        x.src='blue.png';
    }
    x.width=image_width.value;
    x.height=image_height.value
    event.preventDefault();
    canvas.appendChild(x);
});
```

This is the Javascript I used, just to see how it works. However when we used different sized images for example we put 3 20x20 and add an 20x40 and finish the rest of the line with 20x20 once i add one more 20x20 it wont start filling the free space to the left of the 20x40, it will start filling to the right of the 20x40.
[This is the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10iaN.png)
I wanted the red to fill in the black space left of the blue. Red=50x10 Blue=50x20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called a "masonry layout" and they are not very straightforward to implement. It usually requires you to change the flow of your content to run in columns instead of rows.

I'm not even sure that your exact scenario can be accomplished without manual placement, but here is an example of a vertical masonry layout (source: https://codepen.io/iamsaief/pen/jObaoKo):

```css
/* Reset CSS */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #190f2c, #200b30);
    padding: 15px;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Main CSS */
.grid-wrapper > div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.grid-wrapper > div > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.grid-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(75px, 1fr));
    grid-auto-rows: 100px;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
}
.grid-wrapper .wide {
    grid-column: span 2;
}
.grid-wrapper .tall {
    grid-row: span 2;
}
.grid-wrapper .big {
    grid-column: span 2;
    grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">
    <div>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541845157-a6d2d100c931?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588282322673-c31965a75c3e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1351&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="tall">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588117472013-59bb13edafec?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=500&amp;q=60" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="wide">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587588354456-ae376af71a25?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src=" https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558980663-3685c1d673c4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1000&amp;q=60" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="tall">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588499756884-d72584d84df5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=2134&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="big">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588492885706-b8917f06df77?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1951&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588247866001-68fa8c438dd7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=564&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="wide">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586521995568-39abaa0c2311?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="big">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1572914857229-37bf6ee8101c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1951&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="tall">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588453862014-cd1a9ad06a12?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588414734732-660b07304ddb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=675&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588224575346-501f5880ef29?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=700&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1574798834926-b39501d8eda2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=800&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547234935-80c7145ec969?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1353&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="wide">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588263823647-ce3546d42bfe?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=675&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587732608058-5ccfedd3ea63?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587897773780-fe72528d5081?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1489&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="wide">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588083949404-c4f1ed1323b3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1489&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587572236558-a3751c6d42c0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="wide">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583542225715-473a32c9b0ef?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="big">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1527928159272-7d012024eb74?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553984840-b8cbc34f5215?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1433446787703-42d5bf446876?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1351&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="big">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541187714594-731deadcd16a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=700&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="tall">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1540979388789-6cee28a1cdc9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1421930866250-aa0594cea05c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1355&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1493306454986-c8877a09cbeb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1381&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="wide">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1536466528142-f752ae7bdd0c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1350&amp;q=80" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```